# Is there a theory on the creation and genesis of fields?

Tags: field-theory, soft-question, foundations

I do not intend to ask theological questions on PSE, so, you can interpret, if you want, this question on a purely physical basis.

Almost everywhere, in classical and non-classical physical theories, there are various fields mentioned, but, as far as I know, there is no explanation of how fields emerged, that is, where do they come from?

So, is it an "implicit assumption" that fields are eternal and exist always and always will exist, no matter of what is happening in the universe?

For example, we could ask were there any fields before the Big Bang, if Big Bang ever happened at all?

If we accept as truth that fields really exist, it is natural to ask how did they started to exist, if they started at all?

Yes, I could say: "God created the fields, or, some universal field that generates all other fields, and everything else is a consequence of the physical laws.", but I think I ain´t gonna say that.

Is there any physically sound explanation of fields, that is, an explanation that is a model of the genesis of fields?

Of course, we could say that fields are only a mathematicophysical concept that has nothing to do with real causes, but is that really true?

I expect that these questions will not really be welcomed, but surely someone has something to write about this, and I am interested in what is your opinion about all of this?

Comment: Fields arise from symmetries of spacetime, e.g. $U(1)$ yields electromagnetism.

Comment: some fields have (or may have in a future) an explanation and some do not. You must understand that you must start your model with something, you cannot create the model without any assumptions. Then you can philosophy how these assumptions came about. Then physics finds these assumptions are actually consequences of other assumptions and you can philosophy exactly the same thing about these new assumptions. It is like in creationism - God created universe, but who created God? You must start with something.

Comment: @Umaxo Which fields don't have an explanation?

Comment: @safesphere depends on what you call an explanation. As far as i know U(1) does not fix electromagnetic field uniquely, or does it?  I dont really know much about gauge theories. Also how about gravitation?...Anyway i just wanted to point out, that you need some starting structure so you will have always place for philosophy about god and genesis and stuff.

Comment: @Umaxo "Explanation" is a quote from your comment, so it means whatever you mean by it. $U(1)$ is the principle, from which the field equations follow, so it does define the field completely. Gravity is based on the spacetime symmetry of diffeomorphism, e.g. the principle of equivalence of the gravitational and inertial forces.

Comment: @safesphere What is a "the principle of equivalence of the gravitational and inertial forces"? How it is usually phrased?

Comment: @Umaxo I understand your "point of view".

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle

Comment: @safesphere Is this accelerated frame of reference supposed to accelerate at a constant rate, that is, is the derivative of acceleration equal to zero?

Comment: @safesphere Then how about mass of an electron? Or is this just considered electron field and not electromagnetic? And also what does diffeomorphism symmetry has to do with spacetime? Diffeomorphism symmetry just means you can pick any coordinates to describe spacetime. Anyway, i am starting to feel this too broad to discuss it here...

Comment: @Umaxo Is it not that mass explained by the aid of Higgs field?

Comment: Acceleration is equivalent to gravity. A time derivative of acceleration is called jerk. What jerk is equivalent to is not a simple question. Perhaps to gravitational waves, but this may be more complicated. Try searching this forum for jerk or snap, which is a time derivative of jerk.

Comment: @Umaxo The mass of the electron is the energy of its interactions. It does not follow only from $U(1)$, because the electron also participates in other types of interactions besides electromagnetic. Diffeomorphism means that, for example, in a free fall you can locally map the spacetime to Minkowski that would represent the equivalence principle. More generally, diffeomorphism means that gravity is a curvature of spacetime.

Comment: @safesphere But how can something curve if it is not material? "curvature of spacetime" sounds like a nonsense, unless there is an ether?

Comment: "*Recapitulating, we may say that according to the general theory of relativity space is endowed with physical qualities; in this sense, therefore, there exists an ether. According to the general theory of relativity space without ether is unthinkable; for in such space there not only would be no propagation of light, but also no possibility of existence for standards of space and time (measuring-rods and clocks), nor therefore any space-time intervals in the physical sense.*" - Albert Einstein

Answer (score 0):

You have come to a main milestone (based on the comments), and that is asking how forces act on spacetime.

Now with gravity, it is a little bit easier to understand (and be tricked into thinking there is something that bends), because we say "gravity bends spacetime".

Now your question is basically how. In reality we do not know. We do not know whether anything bends or if spacetime actually has a fabric or not. We do not know how it bends if it does at all.

Why do we say then that gravity bends spacetime? There are two main reasons why we use this phrase:

1. gravity is always attractive, so you know that it will always bend in one direction
2. gravity acts on all known elementary particles in the SM, so in our experiments, all particles will have a bent trajectory

So when we say "gravity bends spacetime", we mean that gravity has an effect on spacetime, so that in the area where there is a gravitational field, it will have an effect on spacetime so that all particles that interact with the field will have a bent trajectory.

Now to understand why we do not really know what bends or how it bends is to check out the same way the EM force.

In the case of electromagnetism, we do not use the phrase "electromagnetism bends spacetime" because:

1. the EM force is not always attractive, it can be repulsive, so we do not know which way spacetime would bend, and how it would bend in both ways
2. the EM force does not act on all known elementary particles in the SM, only some, so we cannot say, that sometimes spacetime is bent by the EM force, sometimes it is not

Now, what we do know, is that the EM force has an effect on spacetime, so that in the area where there is an EM field, the EM field will have an effect on spacetime so that some particles will have a bent trajectory when they interact with the field.

Now we do not know what bends, how it bends, or if there is a fabric of spacetime at all.

Now you are asking how these fields emerged. In reality we do not know. Fields are an intrinsic property of spacetime, they exist in all of space since the big bang.

I think you are confused by the word field. And that we use spacetime and fields separately. Actually we do not know if they are separate entities or not. All we know, is that in experiments, fields are always there in all of spacetime.

You are getting confused I think because of we sometimes talk about particles as entities separate from spacetime and fields. They are all one. Fields are spacetime itself (or a property of it), and particles are excitation of the fields. They only exist together. So the answer to your question is that fields exist together with spacetime since spacetime exists.